# How to prove these relations

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory

I have following three basic recurrence relations
$$\mathcal U_{k+1}=A(I+\mathcal U_{k}Q)^{-1}\mathcal U_{k}A^{\mathrm T}+G\\
\mathcal V_{k+1}=\mathcal V_{k}(I+Q\mathcal U_{k})^{-1}A^{\mathrm T}\\
\mathcal W_{k+1}=\mathcal W_{k}+\mathcal V_{k}(I+Q\mathcal U_{k})^{-1}Q\mathcal V_{k}^{\mathrm T}
$$
where all the matrices are square, $I$ is the identity, $A$, $Q$, $G$ are the given constant matrices that $A$ nonsingular, $Q\succeq O$, $G\succeq O$, $(A,G)$ controllable, $(Q,A)$ observable. $\mathcal U_{k}$, $\mathcal V_{k}$, $\mathcal W_{k}$ are variables, $\mathcal U_{0}=O$, $\mathcal V_{0}=I$, $\mathcal W_{0}=O$, $k=0,1,2,\cdots$. ($O$ is the zero matrix)

My question is how to prove the following?

> 1. rank$(\mathcal W_{k+1})>$rank$(\mathcal W_{k})$ when $\mathcal W_{k}$ does not have full rank (positive semidefinite)
> 2. rank$(\mathcal W_{k+1})=$rank$(\mathcal W_{k})$ when $\mathcal W_{k}$ has full rank (positive definite)

The second one is obvious since $\mathcal V_{k}$ is nonsingular, but how about the first one? Thanks in advance!

Comment: $(I + QG)$ must be invertible. Could you edit the question adding the definitions of "controllable" and "observable"? For what I remember, full rank of those matrices is required, right? As a small suggestion on notation, use $\mathbf{O}$ to denote the zero matrix ($0$ denotes the number zero, as in $k=0,1,2,\dots$, thus avoiding notational abuse). Are you sure the first relation is the only one with $\mathcal{U}_k Q$ instead of $Q \mathcal{U}_k$ ?

Comment: @PseudoRandom Thanks for your comment! It is not clear but controllability and observability are the concepts in control theory, and matrices need not to be full rank. The first three relations are correct.

Comment: Ok for controllability and observability, in the sense that I understand what you are speaking about (but that's pretty much it, I don't actually remember anything useful). Unfortunately, I do not know how to help you at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

We can find

$$U_1=G,~~ U_2=A(I+GQ)^{-1}GA^T+G$$
$$V_1=A^T,~~ V_2=A^T(I+QG)^{-1}A^T$$
$$W_1=Q,~~ W_2=Q+A^T(I+QG)^{-1}QA$$

We also know that $(A,Q)$ is observable if and only if

$$\begin{bmatrix}Q \\ QA \\ \vdots \\ QA^{n-1}\end{bmatrix} v = 0$$

implies $v=0$.

Now suppose $\text{rank}Q=r$. Then there exists $n-r$ **linearly independent** vectors $v_i$ such that $Qv_i=W_1 v_i=0$. Now let us look at $W_2 v_i$,

$$\begin{align*}
W_2 v_i &= (Q+A^T(I+GQ)^{-1}QA)v_i \\
  &= A^T(I+GQ)^{-1}QAv_i
\end{align*}$$

Since $A^T$ and $(I+GQ)^{-1}$ are full rank matrices, they do not affect the following discussion.

From the observability assumption $QAv_i \neq 0$ for some $v_i$.

*If it was, $\text{Ker}Q$ would be $A$-invariant, i.e. $QA^kv_i=0$ for all $k>0$ and $v_i \in \text{Ker}Q$, which would be a contradiction to observability assumption.*

**Explanation:** By definition $v \in \text{Ker}Q$ if $Q v = 0$. Let $Q A v = 0$ for all $v \in \text{Ker}Q$. This means $v_1 := Av \in \text{Ker}Q$ also. So, $Q A v_1 = Q A^2 v = 0$. Similarly, $Q A^k v = 0$ for all $v \in \text{Ker}Q$ and $k > 0$. More generally a subspace $\mathcal{S}$ is said to be $A$-invariant if $A v \in \mathcal{S}$ for all $v \in \mathcal{S}$. A good reference is [here](http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee363/lectures/inv-sub.pdf).
What I wanted to say there must exist some vectors such that $Q v = 0$ but $Q A v \neq 0$ from the observability assumption.

Therefore, we conclude that $\text{rank}W_2 > \text{rank}W_1$ if $W_1$ is not full rank.

We now select the vectors in $v_i$ such that $QAv_i=0$ and denote them as $v'_i$. Note that the count of $v'_i$ must be less than $n-r$ from the previous discussion. We now know that $W_2 v'_i=0$, so let us look at $W_3 v'_i$.

$$\begin{align*}
W_3 v'_i &= (W_2 + V_2 (I+QU_2)^{-1}QV_2^T)v'_i \\
  &= V_2 (I+QU_2)^{-1}QA(I+QG)^{-T}Av'_i
\end{align*}$$

Similarly, we can focus on $QA(I+QG)^{-T}Av'_i$ part. Here, we can use the Matrix Inversion Lemma to obtain

$$\begin{align*}
QA(I+QG)^{-T}Av'_i &= QA(I-G^T(I+GQ)^{-T}Q^T)Av'_i \\
  &= QA^2v'_i-G(I+GQ)^{-T}QAv'_i \\
  &= QA^2v'_i
\end{align*}$$

where we used the symmetricity of $G$ and $Q$. Similarly, $QA^2v'_i\neq0$ for some of the $v'_i$. Hence, $\text{rank}W_3 > \text{rank}W_2$.

By putting $U_k$ for $G$ in the above equations we can continue selecting $v$ such that $QA^kv=0$ from the set of vectors such that $QA^{k-1}v=0$ at each step. If at some point $\text{rank}W_k=n$, this means there is no vector exists that we can select from, hence $\text{rank}W_{k+1} = \text{rank}W_k$.

**Explanation:** We need to show that there exists vectors such that $W_k v = 0$ but $W_{k+1} v \neq 0$. This is the same as finding $v$ such that $Q V_k^T v = 0$ but $Q V_{k+1}^T v \neq 0$. I tried to show that this is also equivalent finding $v$ such that $Q A^{k} v = 0$ but $Q A^{k+1} v \neq 0$. To see that write the definition to obtain

$$\begin{align*}
Q V_{k+1}^T v &= QA(I+QU_k)^{-T}V_k^T v \\
  &= QA(I-U_k^T(I+U_kQ)^{-T}Q^T)V_k^T v \\
  &= QAV_k^T v - QAU_k^T(I+U_kQ)^{-T}Q V_k^T v \\
  &= QA V_k^T v
\end{align*}$$

Since $V_1 = A^T$, it follows from the induction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What you need and described in your proof is just **$\bf (Q,A)$ is observable**, not $(A,Q)$. By the way, your proof is a bit confusing. I have three questions in the following.

Comment: 1. The proof by contradiction for rank$W_2>$rank$W_1$, what's your assumption? Is it the contrary of $QAv_i\neq 0$ for some $v_i$, i.e. $QAv_i=0,$ $\forall v_i$? 2. What do you mean of $A$-invariant? Can you show some links about that? But here it is easy to set examples that what you said, $QA^kv_i=0$, $\forall k>0$, $\forall v_i\in\ker Q$, is untrue. 3. The structure of your proof is mathematical induction? But it seems not. The end of your proof for the general case is unclear. In my opinion, you can not neglect the fact of $V_k$, not only simply replacing $G$ by $U_k$, it's not enough.

Comment: The observability of $(Q,A)$ doesn't make any sense. Because $A$ is nonsingular, $(Q,A)$ is always observable whatever the $Q$ is. For your other questions see my edits.

Comment: I mean you are right. Refer to the book _Robust and Optimal control_-Kemin Zhou: $\bf (Q,A)$ is observable iff $$\begin{bmatrix}Q\\QA\\\vdots\\QA^{n-1}\end{bmatrix}v=0$$ implies $v=0$. It's $\bf (Q,A)$, not $(A,Q)$.

Comment: I didn't see an observability definition like this but it is OK if the definition is like this.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks very much for your proof, especially the explanation! When I myself did this, I also expected to suppose the contrary and find the contradiction to the observability, but was stuck in writing the expression as $QA$, $QA^2$ and so forth. Yes, Matrix Inversion Lemma is a good technique.